# Template specification compile error in g++

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors

I have a container object that is templatized. I am trying to make a specialized constructor for `float` versions. Problem is, when the compiler attempts to compile the second object that uses the `float` version, I get a `multiple definition of` error.

**NOTES:** The entire class in in the `h` file. The file is wrapped with a definition (`#ifndef`, `#define`, and `#endif`). g++ version 3.4.6. This compiles fine with other compilers, e.g. Intel's icc.

Code is similar to the following:

```
template <typename T>
class Container {
public:
   Container();
   virtual ~Container() {}
private:
   std::vector<T> data;
   // other members
};

template <> Container<float>::Container() {
   // do something special
}

template <typename T> Container<T>::Container() {
   // do default initialization
}
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

**EDIT** The objects being compiled are also going into separate shared objects, not sure if that has something to do with it.

Comment: g++ 4.0.1 is fine with it as well. Upgrade?

Comment: At the moment, I am unable to do so, or believe me I would. I am locked into that version for this application.

Comment: Just for testing sake, I copied the code to a box that has g++ 4.1.1, and got the same error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Specializations still must abide by the one-definition rule just like any other non-template method. Either mark it inline or define the method body in a source file (not your header).

Answer (score 1):

```
template <> Container<float>::Container() {
   // do something special
}
```

is a **definition** of the specialisation. A specialisation has to be **declared** in every compilation unit it is used:

```
template <> Container<float>::Container();
```

and defined in **only one** of the CU.  So your `.h` has to have the declaration and you have to find an adequate (probably new) `.cpp` for the definition. (As Mark B point out, making the specialization inline is also a way to allow to put the definition in all compilation unit where it is needed).

Answer (score 1):

This is tricky.  The problem is that your specialization is not a 
template, but an actual function definition.  And since it's in a
header, you get multiple definitions when you include it twice.
Something like:

```
template<> Container<float>::Container();
```

in the header, and the implementation in a single source file.

Answer (score -4):

you could use `typeid`:

```
template <typename T> Container<T>::Container() {
   if(typeid(T)==typeid(float)) {
      // do something special
   }
   else {
      // do default initialization
   }
}
```

downside: you cant use initialization list for your special case.
EDIT:
When i wrote this answer, i still assumed that the error was caused by the compiler, not by the code of the OP (did not look into it that much). However this typeid approach is absolutely valid C++ (see link below), and its a quite nice workaround if templates indeed would not work correctly with your specific compiler, and it can easily be replaced by the template solution if once day you can switch to a better compiler.

demonstration: [example @ ideone](http://ideone.com/35uVg)

Comment: Isn't that just bad design? Because that attempt throws away all the possibilities provided by templates.

Comment: @tgmath: i aggree, that most often code that uses `typeid` represents bad design. But in the case, that the parameter given to `typeid` is a type and not an object, it is not that bad. Of course when possible templates you should be used instead.

Comment: @f4: no. i dont think so. see my link.

Comment: @smerlin if an operation is valid on the type float and not on some other T type, you'll have a compilation error. This can be avoided with templates specialization.